# Help proving $cl(E)$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I am to prove that cl(E) is closed. The only two definitions for closure that I am allowed to work with are that cl(E) $ = \{x \in X: \forall $ neighborhoods $U$ of $ x, U\cap E \neq \emptyset\}$ and cl(E) = $X \setminus(X\setminus E)^{\circ}$, where $x \in E^{\circ}$ means there exists a neighborhood $U$ of x such that $x \in U \subset E$.

I **cannot** use limits, boundaries, open balls, cl(E) $= E \cup E$', or the fact that cl(E) is the smallest closed set containing E.

So I want to show cl(E) is closed by showing $X \setminus$cl(E) is open. Here's what I have so far...

Proof sketch: Let $y \in X \setminus$cl(E). Since $y \notin$ cl(E), there exists a neighborhood $U$ of y such that $U\cap E = \emptyset$. Clearly $y \in U$ and since $U\cap E = \emptyset$, then y $\in X\setminus E$. At this point I'm thinking I can say that by the above definition of interior, $y \in (X \setminus E)^{\circ}$, because $U \subset (X \setminus E)$. I am not allowed to use the fact that the interior of a set is open, so now I am feeling stuck.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated, but please do not post full answers.

Comment: To clarify, I get you are **forbidden** from using the **definition** $cl(E)=E \cap E'$, but are you **forbidden** from proving $cl(E)=E \cap E'$ from an allowed definition and then using $cl(E)=E \cap E'$? I.e. you say 'cannot use', do you really mean 'cannot use' and not 'cannot assume' ?

Comment: The teacher has not yet introduced the concept of limit points, so I think it would be inappropriate to bring it into my proof. I wish I could!

Comment: Wait about $cl(E)=E \cup E$? Btw [it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(topology)#Closure_of_a_set)'s $\cup$ not $\cap$

Comment: $\partial$E has been introduced, as $\partial$E = cl(E) $\setminus$ $E^{\circ}$ or equivalently $\partial$E $ = \{x \in X: \forall $ neighborhoods $U$ of $ x, U\cap E \neq \emptyset$ and $U\cap (X \setminus E) \neq \emptyset \}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in cl(E)^c$. Then there exists $U \subseteq X$ an open neighborhood of $x$ such that $E \cap U = \emptyset$. Try to show that $U \cap cl(E) = \emptyset$, and conclude that $cl(E)^c$ is open.

EDIT: I edited away a lot of the answer since OP does not want full answers.

Comment: I'm not seeing how showing that $U \cap cl(E) = \emptyset$ will help me conclude that $cl(E)^c$ is open?

Comment: If $U \cap cl(E) = \emptyset$ then $U \subseteq cl(E)^c$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, this means we can cover $cl(E)^c$ by open sets

Comment: Oh I see! So suppose bwoc that $y \in U \cap cl(E)$. Then $y \in cl(E)$, so $\forall U'$ neighborhoods of $y$, we have $U' \cap E \neq \emptyset$. Since $U$ is one such neighborhood, we have $U \cap E \neq \emptyset$, a contradiction. So $y \notin U \cap cl(E)$ for all y. So $U \subset (X \setminus cl(E))$, which means we can cover  $X \setminus cl(E)$ by open sets. Thus $cl(E)$ is closed. Thank you for your help!